# Using observeEvent() with 500 modals in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

This is my server (module) code from my shiny App:

```
    page_Server <- function(id) {
      moduleServer(id,
                   function(input, output, session) {
                     ns <- NS(id)
                     1:551 %>%
                       map(
                         ~    
                           observeEvent(input[[all_images_ID[.x]]], {
                             showModal(modalDialog(size = 'l',
                                                   easyClose = TRUE,
                                                   h1(all_images_path[.x]),
                                                   img(src = all_images_path[.x])))
                           })
                       )
}
```

When I click the images the modal appears. But when I am clicking over the and over again starts to repeat the same image

But when I right this harded code bellow 551 times

```
     observeEvent(input[[all_images_ID[1]]], {
                       showModal(modalDialog(size = 'l',
                                             easyClose = TRUE,
                                             h1('Text'),
                                             img(src = all_images_path[1])))
                     })
                     observeEvent(input[[all_images_ID[2]]], {
                       showModal(modalDialog(size = 'l',
                                             easyClose = TRUE,
                                             h1('Text'),
                                             img(src = all_images_path[2])))
                     })
    #untill ....

observeEvent(input[[all_images_ID[551]]], {
                       showModal(modalDialog(size = 'l',
                                             easyClose = TRUE,
                                             h1('Text'),
                                             img(src = all_images_path[551])))
                     })
```

Everything goes all right

Why this is happening?

Using map to multiply the number of observe events is a problem?

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: I suspect because in `observeEvent(input[[all_images_ID[.x]]]`, you haven't namespaced your input id.  But without an MRE, it's impossible to be sure.  (When you reference a widget using `$` inside a module, Shiny handles the namespacing for you.  When you access it using a string and `[[]]`, you need to do the namespacing manually.)  As an aside, handling 551 widgets in a single module seems strabge to me.  I think I'd rather have 551 instances of a module, each handling a single widget...

Comment: @Limey can you help me understand why you suggested deal with multiples modules for each image? This has something to do with performance?

Comment: About the namespace behind my app I will have this control. I will check more about this.

Comment: Not so much performance - it's impossible to say without more information - but mainly because of simplicity of code.  For example, if each instance of the module is repsonsible for handling a single widget, the need for subscripting the widgets goes away.  As does the need to use `map`.  Etc, etc.  The code is simpler, so maintenace and bug fixes are easier.  program logic is easier to follow.  Etc, etc....